# How to use c# code inside <% ... %> tags on asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing an asp.net user control. It has a property, FurtherReadingPage, and two controls bound to it: ObjectDataSource and a Repeater. Inside the Repeater I would like to display a hyperlink with an href property set to something like `FurtherReadingPage + "?id=" + Eval("Id")`. I don't know how to do it inside the page's markup. I can use `<% Eval("Id") %>` or `<% Response.Write(FurtherReadingPage + "?id=") %>` alone but I don't know how to mix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this -

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="Server" ID="hlLink" NavigateUrl='<%# FurtherReadingPage + "?Id=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")  %>' />
```

Answer (score 25):

You have a couple of different tags:

`<%` executes the code inside:

```
<% int id = int.Parse(Request["id"]); %>
```

`<%=` writes out the code inside:

```
<%=id %> <!-- note no ; -->

<!-- this is shorthand for: -->
<% Response.Write(id); %>
```

Both of these break up the normal flow when rendered on a page, for instance if you use them in a normal Asp.net `<head runat="server">` you'll get problems.

`<%#` databinding:

```
<%# Eval("id") %>
```

This allows you to specify the bindings for controls that Asp.net WebForms render as a collection (rather than the literal controls that you can use `<%=` with), for instance:

```
<!-- this could be inside a repeater or another control -->
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" ID="demo" 
     NavigateUrl="page.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>" />

<%  //without this bind the <%# will be ignored
    void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        demo.DataBind(); 
        //or
        repeaterWithManyLinks.DataBind(); 
    } 
%>
```

For your specific case you either:

- Use a repeater and `<%# Eval(...) %>` with `repeater.DataBind();`

or

- Use a foreach loop (`<% foreach(... %>`) with `<%= ... %>`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<%#String.Format("{0}?id={1}",FurtherReadingPage, Id)%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (example as link): `<a href='<%=FurtherReadingPage %>?id=<%# Eval("Id") %>'>My link</a>`

Comment: This mixes <%= and <%#, which will create problems in most circumstances. <%= won't work inside a Repeater and <%# won't work unless DataBind() is called.

Comment: @Keith: You are wrong. I just tried <%= "Test" %> inside a repeater to double check and it works ok. <%# only works with Databind() which is the case.

Comment: Sorry, yes, <%= can work in repeaters, depending on the control hierarchy above not containing any collection style controls. Basically <%= FurtherReadingPage %> will sometimes work in a repeater, while <%# FurtherReadingPage %> always will.