# How can I output variable from C# class to aspx file (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm unable to output variable from code behind to aspx file. Please help me out, I'll be thankful.
Here is code of aspx.cs and aspx files:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String Marks = (String) (Session["Marks"]);                
}
```

Here is code of aspx file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>            
        <h1> <%=Marks%> </h1>            
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use c# code inside <% ... %> tags on asp.net page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158424/how-to-use-c-sharp-code-inside-tags-on-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code snippet

```
<h1><% =Session["Marks"]%></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access variables from the code behind. However you can access session in aspx page. So use `Session["Marks"]`